# Generating tensor expression with macro

Tags: macros, expl3, expansion

I am trying to create a command that given a comma separated list of subscript indices,
subscript values, superscript indices, superscript values and then name of the tensor generates the following output:
[image]

I have managed to write a macro which generates the first part, namely the indices and their values:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m m m m}
{
    \seq_new:N \l_test_subi_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_subi_seq { #1 }
    \seq_new:N \l_test_subn_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_subn_seq { #2 }
    \seq_new:N \l_test_supi_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_supi_seq { #3 }
    \seq_new:N \l_test_supn_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_supn_seq { #4 }
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_test_subi_seq }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\mbox{\tiny $\seq_item:Nn \l_test_subi_seq {##1}=\seq_item:Nn \l_test_subn_seq {##1}$} \quad}
    }
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_test_supi_seq }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\mbox{\tiny $\seq_item:Nn \l_test_supi_seq {##1}=\seq_item:Nn \l_test_supn_seq {##1}$} \quad}
    }
    {\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
}
```

However as soon as I try to create a token list for the tensor I get problems. For example, if we ignore for the moment the input for the tensor name, I could attempt to include another token list as follows:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m m m m}
{
    \seq_new:N \l_test_subi_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_subi_seq { #1 }
    \seq_new:N \l_test_subn_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_subn_seq { #2 }
    \seq_new:N \l_test_supi_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_supi_seq { #3 }
    \seq_new:N \l_test_supn_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_supn_seq { #4 }
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_test_subi_seq }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\mbox{\tiny $\seq_item:Nn \l_test_subi_seq {##1}=\seq_item:Nn \l_test_subn_seq {##1}$} \quad}
    }
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_test_supi_seq }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\mbox{\tiny $\seq_item:Nn \l_test_supi_seq {##1}=\seq_item:Nn \l_test_supn_seq {##1}$} \quad}
    }
    {\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpb_tl
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_test_supi_seq }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {\sp\seq_item:Nn \l_test_supn_seq {##1}} 
    }
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_test_subi_seq }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {\sb\seq_item:Nn \l_test_supn_seq {##1}} 
    }
    {\tensor{A}{\tl_use:N \_tmpb_tl}}
}
```

and then I get,

```
 Package tensor Error: Sub/Superscript items out of order on input line 780, 
(tensor)                some index tokens may now have been lost.
```

If instead I use a hack by writing,

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m m m m}
{
    \seq_new:N \l_test_subi_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_subi_seq { #1 }
    \seq_new:N \l_test_subn_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_subn_seq { #2 }
    \seq_new:N \l_test_supi_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_supi_seq { #3 }
    \seq_new:N \l_test_supn_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_supn_seq { #4 }
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_test_subi_seq }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\mbox{\tiny $\seq_item:Nn \l_test_subi_seq {##1}=\seq_item:Nn \l_test_subn_seq {##1}$} \quad}
    }
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_test_supi_seq }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\mbox{\tiny $\seq_item:Nn \l_test_supi_seq {##1}=\seq_item:Nn \l_test_supn_seq {##1}$} \quad}
    }
    {\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpb_tl
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_test_supi_seq }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {\seq_item:Nn \l_test_supn_seq {##1}} 
    }
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpc_tl
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_test_subi_seq }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpc_tl {\seq_item:Nn \l_test_supn_seq {##1}} 
    }
    {{A\sp{\l_tmpc_tl}}\sb{\l_tmpb_tl}}
}
```

the code works fine.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to expand out the `^` and `_` before passing to `\tensor`

you did not provde a test document, but something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tensor}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m m m m}
{
    \seq_new:N \l_test_subi_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_subi_seq { #1 }
    \seq_new:N \l_test_subn_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_subn_seq { #2 }
    \seq_new:N \l_test_supi_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_supi_seq { #3 }
    \seq_new:N \l_test_supn_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_supn_seq { #4 }
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_test_subi_seq }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\mbox{\tiny $\seq_item:Nn \l_test_subi_seq {##1}=\seq_item:Nn \l_test_subn_seq {##1}$} \quad}
    }
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_test_supi_seq }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\mbox{\tiny $\seq_item:Nn \l_test_supi_seq {##1}=\seq_item:Nn \l_test_supn_seq {##1}$} \quad}
    }
    {\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpb_tl
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_test_supi_seq }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpb_tl {\sp{\seq_item:Nn \l_test_supn_seq {##1}}} 
    }
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_test_subi_seq }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpb_tl {\sb\seq_item:Nn {\l_test_subn_seq {##1}}} 
    }
    {\exp_args:NnV\tensor{A}\l_tmpb_tl}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\[
\test{a,b,c,d}{1,2,3,4}{e,f,g,h}{5,6,7,8}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: it's not clear if you really need `\tensor` at all here. Having got the lists you could just typeset the result rather than construct a combined list for `\tensor` to re-parse, but I answered the general expl3 expansion issue here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still do not understand why expl3 requires an \exp_args: command. In the other version where I use a hack expansion is not required. Is it the tensor command that is causing the issue?

Comment: @TedBlack yes `\tensor`  parses its argument "by hand" looking for multiple `^` and `_` and constructing a tex layout, but you gave it an argument with no `^` or `_`  but `\sp{\item{1}}\sp{\item{2}....`  which it can't parse at all.  But as I commented I can't see why you want tensor here especially if you have just one subscript and one superscript rather than multiple interleaved ones

Comment: @TedBlack nothing to do with expl3 really try `\def\xsp{^}\def\xsb{_}\tensor{\xsp{a}\xsp{a}\xsb{b}\xsb{b}}`  and it will error, exp_args just allows you to expand the argument first so `\tensor` sees `{^{a}^{a}_{b}_{b}}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I keep misunderstanding basic facts about expansion. I will need the tensor package because the expressions will involve multiple superscripts and subscripts.

Comment: @TedBlack I can't really see why but OK. all tensor package is doing here is parsing `\tensor{A}{^a_b^c_d}` into separate lists a,b,c,d and then constructing a layout, but you are starting with separate lists, then making a combined list for `\tensor` to split up.

Answer (score 2):

There are simpler loops to get the job done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tensor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mytens}{mmmm}
 {
  \tedblack_mytens:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__tedblack_mytens_up_names_seq
\seq_new:N \l__tedblack_mytens_up_values_seq
\seq_new:N \l__tedblack_mytens_down_names_seq
\seq_new:N \l__tedblack_mytens_down_values_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tedblack_mytens:nnnn
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__tedblack_mytens_up_names_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__tedblack_mytens_up_values_seq { #2 }
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__tedblack_mytens_down_names_seq { #3 }
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__tedblack_mytens_down_values_seq { #4 }
  % print the list of values
  \seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN
    \l__tedblack_mytens_up_names_seq
    \l__tedblack_mytens_up_values_seq
    \__tedblack_mytens_value:nn
  \seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN
    \l__tedblack_mytens_down_names_seq
    \l__tedblack_mytens_down_values_seq
    \__tedblack_mytens_value:nn
  % print the staggered values
  \tensor { A } { \sp{\seq_use:Nn \l__tedblack_mytens_up_values_seq {}} }
                { \sb{\seq_use:Nn \l__tedblack_mytens_down_values_seq {}} }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__tedblack_mytens_value:nn
 {
  #1 = #2 \quad
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\mytens{a,b,c,d}{1,2,3,4}{e,f,g,h}{5,6,7,8}
\]

\end{document}
```

In order to print the “var=value” parts, we can use `\seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN` and for the superscripts and subscripts we can exploit `\seq_use:Nn`.

[image]

Comment: Answers like this are the reason I am still trying to learn `expl3`! My original question only dealt with how to do expansions properly but now I can see I could have avoided this issue altogether.

Comment: It is still not clear why in this case we do not need `\exp_args:` ...

Comment: @TedBlack I don’t store the whole token list in a variable, so `\tensor` has no problem in seeing the various parts.